# Need to count records and group count by date on oracle db using sql developer

Tags: oracle, count, oracle10g, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like the following

```
   ID                created    sent    type
-----------------------------------------------------
0001463583000051783  31-JUL-12  1   270
0081289563000051788  01-AUG-12  1   270
0081289563000051792  01-AUG-12  1   270
0081289563000051791  01-AUG-12  1   270
0081289563000051806  01-AUG-12  1   270
0001421999000051824  06-AUG-12  1   270
0001421999000051826  06-AUG-12  1   270
0001464485000051828  06-AUG-12  1   270
0082162128000051862  09-AUG-12  2   278
0082162128000051861  09-AUG-12  2   278
0022409222082910259  09-AUG-12  3   278
```

I would like to have the following for output

```
created     Count
---------------------
31-JUL-12   1
01-AUG-12   4
06-AUG-12   3
09-AUG-12   3
```

How hard would it be to accomplish this using SQL Developer on Oracle 10g

I have tried several queries to generate such a table and in the end it does not group the count by date just gives me a '1' for the count when we average 5000-10000 transactions daily. Im probably over complicating it. But i would like something simple where i can pull the amount of transactions on a daily basis within a date range.

what is happening currently when i run my queries is

```
created     Count
---------------------
31-JUL-12   1
01-AUG-12   1
01-AUG-12   1
01-AUG-12   1
01-AUG-12   1
06-AUG-12   1
06-AUG-12   1
06-AUG-12   1
09-AUG-12   1
09-AUG-12   1
09-AUG-12   1
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I managed to get this results with this query:

```
select trunc(created), count(*)
from table1
group by trunc(created)
```

Note the `trunc` function, even if you don't display it, the `DATE` datatype holds the time as well

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e455a/3) is a fiddle